# Should GetMediaURI get the mimeType?

Tags: sonos

The service I am trying to integrate with Sonos is flexible on the audio format and chooses based on different factors such as bandwidth. Unfortunately, the current Sonos workflow requires to returned `mimeType` in `getMediaMetadata` (e.g. when putting the track in the playlist), and then crashes if the encoding of the returned `uri` in `getMediaURI` doesn't match the previously returned `mimeType`.

Could Sonos rely on an optional `mimeType` that would be returned in `getMediaURI` response instead?

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, `mimeType` is not returned in a `getMediaUri` response. We'll forward your suggestion to the team.